# Find all the real solutions of $(1+x^2)(1+x^4)=4x^3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, contest-math

As title suggests, the question is to find all the real roots to the polynomial:

$$(1+x^2)(1+x^4)=4x^3$$

This problem was asked in the Kettering University Math Olympiad a few years back, it's an interesting problem with many different ways to approach it. I'm going to share my own approach here, please make sure to let me know if there are any mistakes in mine or if anything can be improved, and share your own methods too!

Here's my approach for the problem:

$$(1+x^2)(1+x^4)=4x^3$$

Divide by $x^3$ on both sides:

$$\frac{1+x^2}{x}\cdot\frac{1+x^4}{x^2}=4$$

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=4$$

Now we can set $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$, thus, $y^2-2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$

$$y(y^2-2)=4$$

$$y^3-2y-4=0$$

$$y^3-8-2y+4=0$$

$$(y-2)(y^2+2y+4)-2(y-2)=0$$

$$(y-2)(y^2+2y+2)=0$$

Now obviously, since we need to find real solutions, the term $(y^2+2y+2)$ will need to be rejected, as it can easily be checked that it yields no real roots.

[Alternatively, we can set $y^2+2y+2=0$ and observe that $(y+1)^2=-1$, thus this term yields no real solution]

Therefore:

$$y=2$$

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=2$$

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x}=2$$

$$x^2-2x+1=0$$

$$(x-1)^2=0$$

Therefore, $x=1$ is our only real solution.

Comment: Nice solution and (+1)

Comment: Instead of a long sentence ("Now obviously, the term ... will need to be rejected, as it can be easily checked ..."), you could just write $y^2+2y+2=(y+1)^2+1>0$.

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking of showing that the discriminant of that term was $<0$ but yours is a much better approach

Comment: you can do a Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM in one line to get:
$$4x^3 = (1+x^2)(1+x^4)\geq (1+|x|^3)^2 \geq 4|x|^3\implies x = 1.$$

Comment: In a mere line or two? Do you mind posting that approach as an answer? I really want to see what it could be like @dezdichado

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nice answer.

An amusing way is to use AM/GM. First, note that any solution is positive, since the left side is positive, and thus $4x^3$ must be positive, so $x$ must be positive.

Then AM/GM says $$\frac{1+x^2}{2}\geq x\\\frac{1+x^4}{2}\geq x^2$$

So $$\frac{(1+x^2)(1+x^4)}{4}\geq x^3$$ for $x>0,$ with equality only when $1=x^2=x^4.$

Comment: Wow, this absolutely destroyed my answer completely. Inequalities seem to be super useful almost everwhere especially AM-GM inequality. Since this was from a University Olympiad, I believe this is exactly how it was intended to be solved. Elegant approach!

Comment: Your answer was good - it captured an important property that when $x$ is a root then $1/x$ is a root. Your technique generalizes to other symmetric polynomials where mine might not.

Comment: Good point, but still, for this specific case, your approach is probably as elegant as it could get, you'd have most likely score full points on the Olympiad for this problem @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Sure, contests like to award *slick* answers over more general tools. :) @Goku

Comment: For example the question of real solutions to $$(1-x^2)(1+x^4)=4x^3$$ yields an attack via your technique, letting $y=x-1/x$ and getting $y(y^2+2)=4$ and you get there is one real solution $y$ and two solutions $x,$ even if there is no simple closed formula. [Wolfram gives: $$y = \frac{6^{1/3} (9 + \sqrt{87})^{2/3} - 6^{2/3}}{3 (9 + \sqrt{87})^{1/3}}$$]

Answer (score 6):

After expanding, we're trying to find the roots of the polynomial $p(x)=x^6+x^4-4x^3+x^2+1$. Factoring out obvious roots one at time gives

\begin{align*}
p(x)&=x^6+x^4-4x^3+x^2+1\\
&=(x-1)(x^5+x^4+2x^3-2x^2-x-1)\\
&=(x-1)^2(x^4+2x^3+4x^2+2x+1)\\
&=(x-1)^2\left[(x^2+x)^2+2x^2+(x+1)^2\right]
\end{align*}

at which point $x=1$ is clearly the only real root.

Comment: $p(x)=(x^3-1)^2+x^2(x-1)^2$. $\quad p(x)=0\implies x^3-1=x(x-1)=0\implies x=1$.

Comment: Nice answer! I didn't try expanding because I thought it would be difficult to factor but it seems you managed to do it. +1